# Is there a good reason to write my own daemonize function instead of using daemon(3)?

Tags: c, linux, unix, daemon, bsd

There are a lot of example implementations of daemons on the net. Most that I saw do not use the daemon(3) function to run the program in the background. Is that just a matter of taste, ignorance, or is there a good reason to write my own daemonize function? Is there a specific disadvantage in using daemon(3)? Is it insecure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BSD daemon() function is very limited and invites misuse. Only very few daemons may use this function correctly.

The systemd man pages have a list of what a correctly written SysV daemon should do when daemonizing:

http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/daemon.html

Answer (score 5):

The daemon() function was not historically available in all flavors of Unix, so a lot of "portable" code doesn't use it. There's really no reason to roll your own recipe as long as all the target platforms you care about have daemon().

Comment: Not just historically; it's never been standardized and has no standard behavior. Every vendor's may be different or it might not exist at all. Best never to use it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `daemon` function in POSIX. It's a vendor extension. Thus anyone writing portable code simply writes their own.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like any of the standard `daemon()` function actions, you might write your own.  You can control whether it switches to the root directory; you can control whether it reconnects the standard I/O channels to /dev/null.  But if you want to keep stderr open to a log file, while reconnecting stdin and stdout to /dev/null, you have to decide whether to use `daemon()` with appropriate options followed by other code is better than rolling your own.

There isn't much rocket science in `daemon()`; it calls `fork()` and `setsid()` (according to the Linux version; the MacOS version mentions suspending SIGHUP while `daemon()` is operating).  Check out the standard resources for more information on daemonization — for example:

- W. Richard Stevens, Bill Fenner, Andrew M. Rudoff 
  [UNIX® Network Programming, Vol 1: The Sockets Networking API, 3rd Edn](http://unpbook.com/)
- Marc J Rochkind
  [Advanced Unix Programming, 2nd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411543)