# How do I run my server as a daemon process?

Tags: c, sockets, daemon, infinite-loop

For a few days I have been trying to run my server as a daemon process that runs continuously. Right now, my server closes the connection with the client and then closes itself. So I am able to send my packet once to the server, but when I try to send it again I get a segmentation fault error.

Also, even though I wrote the daemon process, I am not sure about its behavior and whether it is working or not.

Server Code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include "unistd.h"
#include <syslog.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAXPROFILES  2

float Pearson(int mySum, int recSum, int multSum);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    unsigned char buf[1024];
    int myDataBinary[500] = {0};
    int myDataBinary2[500] = {0};
    int recData[500] = {0};*/
    int index1=0;

    struct profile_t
    {
        unsigned char length;
        unsigned char type;
        unsigned char *data;
    };

    typedef struct profile_datagram_t
    {
       unsigned char *src;
       unsigned char *dst;
       unsigned char ver;
       unsigned char n;
       struct profile_t profiles[MAXPROFILES];
    } header;


    header outObj;
    int j =0;
    int i =0;

    extern int daemon_proc;   /* defined in error.c */

    void daemon_init (const char *pname, int facility)
    {
   /* Our process ID and Session ID */
       pid_t pid, sid;

       /* Fork off the parent process */
       pid = fork();
       if (pid < 0) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

      /* If we got a good PID, then
       we can exit the parent process. */
       if (pid > 0) {
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

       /* Change the file mode mask */
       umask(0);

       /* Open any logs here */        

       /* Create a new SID for the child process */
       sid = setsid();
       if (sid < 0) {
            /* Log the failure */
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

         /* Change the current working directory */
          if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
            /* Log the failure */
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

         /* Close out the standard file descriptors */
          close(STDIN_FILENO);
          close(STDOUT_FILENO);
          close(STDERR_FILENO);

         /* Daemon-specific initialization goes here */

      }


         if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: %s port_number1",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
     }
          sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
          if (sockfd < 0)
          error("ERROR DETECTED !!! Problem in opening socket");

          bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
          portno = atoi(argv[1]);

          serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
          serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
          serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

          if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
          error("ERROR DETECTED !!! There was a problem in binding");

          listen(sockfd, 10);
          clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    while (1){

      printf("Server listening on port number %d...\n", serv_addr.sin_port);

      newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

      if (newsockfd < 0)
  error("ERROR DETECTED !!! the connection request was not accepted");

  int rc = read(newsockfd,buf,100);
  if(rc < 0){
     printf("error");
 }
 else {
     printf("success %d",rc);
 }


    outObj.src = malloc(4);
    outObj.dst = malloc(4);
            // printf(pointer);
             memcpy(outObj.src,buf+0,4);
             memcpy(outObj.dst,buf+4,4);
             memcpy(&outObj.ver,buf+8,1);
             memcpy(&outObj.n,buf+9,1);

 printf("\nSource IP = ");
 for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
     printf("%d ",outObj.src[i]);
 }

 printf("\nDestination IP = ");
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
     printf("%d ",outObj.dst[i]);
 }

 printf("\nVersion = %d",outObj.ver);
 printf("\nNumber of messages = %d",outObj.n);

 int k = 10;

 for(i=0;i<outObj.n;i++){
            memcpy(&outObj.profiles[i].length,buf+k,1);
            memcpy(&outObj.profiles[i].type,buf+k+1,1);
            outObj.profiles[i].data = malloc(outObj.profiles[i].length);
            memcpy(outObj.profiles[i].data,buf+k+2,5);
            k +=7;
}

for(int i=0;i<outObj.n;i++){
        printf("\n------- Message %d --------",i+1);
        printf("\nLength : %d",outObj.profiles[i].length);
        printf("\nType : %d\n",outObj.profiles[i].type);
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            printf(" Data[%d] : %d",j,outObj.profiles[i].data[j]);
        }
    }

      float rho;

for(int i=0;i<outObj.n;i++){
    printf("\n\n---------- Values for Data Profile %d ------------",i+1);
    index1=0;
    int sumRecievedData = 0;
    int sumMyData = 0;
    int sumMultpliedData = 0;
    int my_data[10] = {0};//  = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int myDataBinary[500] = {0};
    int recData[500] = {0};


    if(i==0){
        my_data[0] = 1;
        my_data[1] = 3;
        my_data[2] = 9;
        my_data[3] = 10;
    } else if(i==1){
        my_data[0] = 1;
        my_data[1] = 2;
        my_data[2] = 3;
        my_data[3] = 4;
        my_data[4] = 5;
    }



    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(my_data)/sizeof(int);i++)
        {
            if(my_data[i] > 0){
                index1 = my_data[i];
                myDataBinary[index1] = 1;
                //printf("my data %d = %d\n",index1,myDataBinary[index1]);
            }
    }

    for (int j=0; j<outObj.profiles[i].length;j++) {

        if(outObj.profiles[i].data[j] > 0){
            index1 = outObj.profiles[i].data[j];
            recData[index1] = 1;
            //printf("rec data %d = %d\n",index1,recData[index1]);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
        sumRecievedData += recData[i];
        sumMyData += myDataBinary[i];
        sumMultpliedData += recData[i] * myDataBinary[i];
    }

    printf("\nrecSum = %d, \nmySum = %d, \nmultSum = %d\n",sumRecievedData,sumMyData,sumMultpliedData);

    rho = Pearson(sumMyData,sumRecievedData,sumMultpliedData);
    printf("\nPearson Coefficient for Data Profile %d= %f\n",i+1,rho);
}


return 0;
   }
    //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }


float Pearson(int mySum, int recSum, int multSum)
{
float Cov =0;
float sdMyData = 0;
float sdRecievedData =0;
float rho;
int n = 500;

Cov = (1.0/(n-1))*(multSum - (1.0/n)*mySum*recSum);
sdMyData = sqrt((1.0/(n-1))*(mySum - (1.0/n)*mySum*mySum));
sdRecievedData = sqrt((1.0/(n-1))*(recSum - (1.0/n)*recSum*recSum));
printf("\nCovariance = %f, \nVarianceMyData = %f, \nVarianceRecData = %f",Cov,sdMyData,sdRecievedData);
if (sdMyData == 0.0 || sdRecievedData == 0.0){
    rho = 0.0;
}else{
    rho = Cov/(sdMyData*sdRecievedData);
}

return(rho);
}
```

Comment: Have you collected a core dump, and use it to establish which line of code caused the seg-fault?

Comment: @Oli: my code runs fine when I execute it once. But now I want this code to keep running in an infinite loop and also daemonize this code.

Comment: @user537670: perhaps fix the looping/state problems before trying to daemonize it.

Comment: @Joe: the looping is solved...now can you guide me with daemonizing the process

Comment: What OS you are on? Did you try searching on google about daemonizing a process? There are many links explaining that.

Comment: Your code is unreadable.  I've partially fixed the tabs vs spaces problems (use spaces only when pasting to SO, or work with tabstops set at 4, not 8).  You have a nested function `daemon_init()`; that is a GCC extension which should be avoided if you have any intention of writing portable code.  You don't call the function, so it is wasted anyway.  You should be using more functions; you have slabs of code in your `main()` function doing a multitude of jobs - it is very uncohesive.  (It also doesn't compile; there's a `*/` marking a comment end without a `/*` for the beginning!)

Comment: I'm gonna be honest and say this is some of the worst code I've ever seen. It's a debugging nightmare and it's literally all just thrown into main...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good reason to write my own daemonize function instead of using daemon(3)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720439/is-there-a-good-reason-to-write-my-own-daemonize-function-instead-of-using-daemon)

Answer (score 1):

The server does `return(0);` at the bottom of the supposedly infinite loop, thus exiting from `main()` and terminating.

As noted in a comment, your code includes a nested function `daemon_init()` which is never called.  Nested functions are a GCC-only feature; you should avoid using them.  If you do call it, the server is going to have problems because it closes `stdout` and `stderr` but your code then tries to write to the now closed files.

Without the client code, it is very far from clear what information is being sent over the wire.  There is one `read()` call:

```
int rc = read(newsockfd,buf,100);
```

That should be using `sizeof(buf)` in place of 100; and it is wasteful to use `char buf[1024];` when you only use 100 bytes.  You check that you got some data; you do not check that you got all the data you expect.  You might, therefore, be reading uninitialized data.

There are numerous other similar problems in the code, especially with constants used somewhat inappropriately.  As also noted in a comment, the code is not properly modularized.

The code does not seem to respond to the client; its outputs only go to its standard output (or error).

This code compiles reasonably cleanly, but still doesn't call `daemon_init()` for the reasons mentioned earlier.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* exit() */
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>   /* umask() */
#include <syslog.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXPROFILES  2

static void error(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int errnum = errno;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    fprintf(stderr, ": %d %s\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    exit(1);
}

static float Pearson(int mySum, int recSum, int multSum);

static void daemon_init(void)
{
    /* Our process ID and Session ID */
    pid_t pid, sid;

    /* Fork off the parent process */
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        error("failed to fork");

    /* If we got a good PID, then
       we can exit the parent process. */
    if (pid > 0)
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    /* Change the file mode mask */
    umask(0);

    /* Open any logs here */        

    /* Create a new SID for the child process */
    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0)
        error("failed to set session ID");

    /* Change the current working directory */
    if ((chdir("/")) < 0)
        error("failed to chdir to root");

    /* Close out the standard file descriptors */
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);

    /* Daemon-specific initialization goes here */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    unsigned char buf[1024];

    struct profile_t
    {
        unsigned char length;
        unsigned char type;
        unsigned char *data;
    };

    typedef struct profile_datagram_t
    {
        unsigned char *src;
        unsigned char *dst;
        unsigned char ver;
        unsigned char n;
        struct profile_t profiles[MAXPROFILES];
    } header;

    header outObj;

    if (argc != 2)
        error("usage: %s port", argv[0]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR DETECTED !!! Problem in opening socket");

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR DETECTED !!! There was a problem in binding");

    listen(sockfd, 10);

    while (1)
    {
        clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
        printf("Server listening on port number %d...\n", serv_addr.sin_port);
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);

        if (newsockfd < 0)
            error("ERROR DETECTED !!! the connection request was not accepted");

        int rc = read(newsockfd,buf,100);
        if (rc < 0)
            error("read error");
        else
            printf("read: success %d", rc);

        outObj.src = malloc(4);
        outObj.dst = malloc(4);
        // printf(pointer);
        memcpy(outObj.src,buf+0,4);
        memcpy(outObj.dst,buf+4,4);
        memcpy(&outObj.ver,buf+8,1);
        memcpy(&outObj.n,buf+9,1);

        printf("\nSource IP = ");
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
            printf("%d ",outObj.src[i]);

        printf("\nDestination IP = ");
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
            printf("%d ",outObj.dst[i]);

        printf("\nVersion = %d",outObj.ver);
        printf("\nNumber of messages = %d",outObj.n);

        int k = 10;

        for (int i=0;i<outObj.n;i++)
        {
            memcpy(&outObj.profiles[i].length,buf+k,1);
            memcpy(&outObj.profiles[i].type,buf+k+1,1);
            outObj.profiles[i].data = malloc(outObj.profiles[i].length);
            memcpy(outObj.profiles[i].data,buf+k+2,5);
            k +=7;
        }

        for (int i=0;i<outObj.n;i++)
        {
            printf("\n------- Message %d --------",i+1);
            printf("\nLength : %d",outObj.profiles[i].length);
            printf("\nType : %d\n",outObj.profiles[i].type);
            for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                printf(" Data[%d] : %d",j,outObj.profiles[i].data[j]);
            }
        }

        for (int i=0;i<outObj.n;i++)
        {
            printf("\n\n---------- Values for Data Profile %d ------------",i+1);
            int index1=0;
            int sumReceivedData = 0;
            int sumMyData = 0;
            int sumMultpliedData = 0;
            int my_data[10] = {0};
            int myDataBinary[500] = {0};
            int recData[500] = {0};

            if (i==0)
            {
                my_data[0] = 1;
                my_data[1] = 3;
                my_data[2] = 9;
                my_data[3] = 10;
            }
            else if (i==1)
            {
                my_data[0] = 1;
                my_data[1] = 2;
                my_data[2] = 3;
                my_data[3] = 4;
                my_data[4] = 5;
            }

            for (int i=0; i<sizeof(my_data)/sizeof(int);i++)
            {
                if (my_data[i] > 0)
                {
                    index1 = my_data[i];
                    myDataBinary[index1] = 1;
                    //printf("my data %d = %d\n",index1,myDataBinary[index1]);
                }
            }

            for (int j=0; j<outObj.profiles[i].length;j++)
            { 
                if (outObj.profiles[i].data[j] > 0)
                {
                    index1 = outObj.profiles[i].data[j];
                    recData[index1] = 1;
                    //printf("rec data %d = %d\n",index1,recData[index1]);
                }
            }

            for (int i=0;i<500;i++)
            {
                sumReceivedData += recData[i];
                sumMyData += myDataBinary[i];
                sumMultpliedData += recData[i] * myDataBinary[i];
            }

            printf("\nrecSum = %d, \nmySum = %d, \nmultSum = %d\n",sumReceivedData,sumMyData,sumMultpliedData);

            float rho = Pearson(sumMyData,sumReceivedData,sumMultpliedData);
            printf("\nPearson Coefficient for Data Profile %d= %f\n",i+1,rho);
        }

        return 0;
    }
    //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

static float Pearson(int mySum, int recSum, int multSum)
{
    float Cov =0;
    float sdMyData = 0;
    float sdReceivedData =0;
    float rho;
    int n = 500;

    Cov = (1.0/(n-1))*(multSum - (1.0/n)*mySum*recSum);
    sdMyData = sqrt((1.0/(n-1))*(mySum - (1.0/n)*mySum*mySum));
    sdReceivedData = sqrt((1.0/(n-1))*(recSum - (1.0/n)*recSum*recSum));
    printf("Covariance = %f\n",Cov);
    printf("VarianceMyData = %f\n",sdMyData);
    printf("VarianceRecData = %f\n",sdReceivedData);
    if (sdMyData == 0.0 || sdReceivedData == 0.0)
        rho = 0.0;
    else
        rho = Cov/(sdMyData*sdReceivedData);

    return(rho);
}
```

It still needs a lot of work.