# Detach forked process from linux service using dbus

Tags: c, linux, service, dbus

I have a service on linux. This service needs to start different processes. For example, on some condition e.g. a network event, the service should start a process that has a GUI.
For this i used fork() and execvp().
I furthermore dropped root privileges by setting the uid and gid according to the user, for which i want to run the process.
I then perceded by setting the DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY environment variables accordingly.

This worked kinda. My process was indeed running and the GUI was displayed. However it is noticable that the process is not really detatched from the service.
For example: pkexec does not work. It always tries to start the terminal version and fails.
Also, i dont want my process to be killed, as soon as the service stops.

I read that for this i should use the dbus and use it to communicate with the systemd and either 1) start the process via systemd or 2) let systemd somehow detatch my process from the service.

Now i dont have any idea how that works. I can open the bus and i should also be able to call methods, however i dont know which method and what i am even trying to do.

Can someone guide me in the right direction, of which method i should call on the systemd to either start a process in a user session or detatch a process from my service.

Disclaimer: setting KillMode=none would solve the process killing issue, however this is, as far as i know, not recommended and also does not solve the pkexec problem.

Comment: _Side note:_ With the `fork/execvp` method, you could/should do a _double_ `fork` and do the `execvp` from the grandchild process. And, you should do `setsid` and/or `setpgrp`. And, you can close `stdin/stdout/stderr` and [optionally] open them on a logfile

Comment: Oh sorry i missed that. Indeed i also tried doing a fork, then `setsid()` and then forking again. and i also closed the std filedescriptors. Thanks i will add `setpgrp()` too. This however still lets my process die when the service stops

Comment: You don't say so explicitly, but I'm inferring from various remarks that your service is being managed by systemd, and that what you specifically want is for a descendant process to survive the service being stopped via systemd (for example, `systemctl stop my.service`).  Is that correct?

Comment: It's unclear how you are trying to use `pkexec` or the nature of the failure.  You say you're already changing uid and gid (I guess via `setuid()` and `setgid()`).  What further use is `pkexec`, then?

Comment: You can see the references in my answer to [Is there a good reason to write my own daemonize function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3720789/15168).  Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3721816/15168) to the same question points to some useful reference material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a service on linux. This service needs to start different processes. For example, on some condition e.g. a network event, the service should start a process that has a GUI

Don't do that. It's a really bad architecture, as you've found out. (Even if you do set DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY, how do you know *what are the correct values* for that? What guarantees that there's always exactly one user? What guarantees their XAUTHORITY is always the same?)

Instead, let the GUI itself start a "listener" process for the logged-in user, which waits for the events (either from system in general, or from your own system service) and simply starts the necessary programs because it's already running as the correct user in the correct cgroup. This "agent" pattern is commonly used in desktop environments; /etc/xdg/autostart is used to automatically start the agent process upon login.

> I read that for this i should use the dbus and use it to communicate with the systemd and either 1) start the process via systemd or 2) let systemd somehow detatch my process from the service.
>
> Now i dont have any idea how that works. I can open the bus and i should also be able to call methods, however i dont know which method and what i am even trying to do.

This is how the systemd approach would work:

1. You can connect to the system service manager and ask it to start a *transient service* with parameters and environment that you specify through the D-Bus call. It will be completely detached from your main service.
2. Or, you can connect to the user's personal systemd instance and ask *that* to start a transient service. The advantage here is that it will automatically have all the necessary environment inherited from the per-user systemd process – it's actually how some desktop environments launch apps nowadays.

   Unlike spawning the process directly, this only requires knowing the user's UID (and XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, but fortunately that *is* guaranteed to be at a fixed per-UID path).
3. Or, you could spawn the process yourself (with the correct environment), then ask systemd to create a transient *scope* which will correspond to a new cgroup.

In all cases, the method call you want is `StartTransientUnit()`, with the only difference being the bus address you connect to. For option #1 it's the system bus; for option #2 you have to switch to the correct UID, then connect to the "user bus" at `/run/user/<uid>/bus`.

Start by experimenting with the `systemd-run` command; you can use dbus-monitor to see what calls it uses. (Or, in fact, you can just spawn systemd-run from your service.) For example:

```
runuser -u $username -- \
    env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$uid \
    systemd-run --user --collect /usr/bin/xterm

systemd-run -M $username@.host --user --collect /usr/bin/xterm
```

Comment: Great explanation, exactly what i wanted. `systemd-run` is perfect for my usecase and solves both of my problems. I would maybe also consider switching up my architecture, but as long as the simple `systemd-run` approach is working, i think i will keep it. Thanks for the great explanation about the transient scope

Answer (score 3):

Prefaced by my top comments ...

1. Do *double* `fork`
2. Do `setsid` in grandchild
3. Do `setpgrp` in grandchild
4. Close all standard units in grandchild

I've created a diagnostic program that appears to work. I've *not* tested it *extensively*. It doesn't set any environment, so I don't know how that will affect things.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void
launch_top(int argc,char **argv)
{
    pid_t top = getpid();

    // parent launching child
    pid_t pcld = fork();
    if (pcld != 0) {
        waitpid(pcld,NULL,0);
        sleep(2);
        printf("launch_top: killing self %d\n",top);
        kill(top,SIGTERM);
        exit(0);
    }

    // child launching grandchild
    pid_t gcld = fork();
    if (gcld != 0)
        exit(0);

    // grandchild launching target
    setsid();
    setpgrp();

    fclose(stdin);
    fclose(stdout);
    fclose(stderr);

    char *av[3];

    av[0] = argv[0];
    av[1] = "forever";
    av[2] = NULL;

    execvp(av[0],av);
    perror("launch_top/execvp");
    exit(9);
}

void
stay_alive(int argc,char **argv)
{

    FILE *xflog = fopen("stay.log","w");
    setlinebuf(xflog);

    for (int loop = 0;  loop < 10;  ++loop) {
        fprintf(xflog,"stay_alive: %d\n",loop);
        sleep(1);
    }

    fprintf(xflog,"stay_alive: success\n");
    fclose(xflog);

    exit(0);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    // ultimate program that should stay alive
    if (argc > 1)
        stay_alive(argc,argv);

    // launcher service
    else
        launch_top(argc,argv);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the `stdout` output for the parent:

```
launch_top: killing self 2564383
```

---

Here is the sample output log `stay.log` for the target program that should stay alive and survive the original/parent being killed:

```
stay_alive: 0
stay_alive: 1
stay_alive: 2
stay_alive: 3
stay_alive: 4
stay_alive: 5
stay_alive: 6
stay_alive: 7
stay_alive: 8
stay_alive: 9
stay_alive: success
```

Comment: FWIW, I've always done `fork()`->`setsid()`->`fork()`, probably because that was how the implementation I first copied from did it.  Offhand, I don't recall if that can matter or not.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I didn't think that doing `setsid` on the [middle] child would do much because it would `fork` but then immediate `exit`. I was prepared to experiment if my first shot didn't work. I'm not even sure whether we need `setsid`, `setpgrp`, or both. This was a kitchen sink approach to get relief fast. There's also a `tcsetpgrp` that uses an `ioctl` that I was prepared to try next [I found it while doing this, but since I've never used/needed it before ...].

Comment: @CraigEstey, I supposed that Andrew meant that the middle child calls `sesid()` *instead of* the grandchild doing so.  That also results in the grandchild being in a different session than the original process, and in that sense, it certainly does do something.  But I agree that it's not useful for both child and grandchild to call `setsid()`.

Comment: @CraigEstey, but in the context implied by the question, I suspect that what is needed is to move the target process out of the service's Linux *control group* (cgroup).  And maybe also to its own pgroup, which seems like the right thing to do even if it's not strictly necessary.  I'm unsure how needful or appropriate it is to move the process to a new session.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, I caught that (re. child vs. gchild doing `setsid`). It's been _years_ since I coded this for a real product. I [vaguely] remember doing `setpgrp`. But, later, IIRC, I had to add `setsid`. One of the reasons I posted the program was so people could experiment. I'd be glad to update with new information.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's exactly what I meant.  FWIW, a quick scan of POSIX [`setpgrp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgrp.html) and [`setsid()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsid.html) seems to read they're effectively identical in their effects for processes not already a session leader.  I don't know offhand how either interacts wth Linux cgroups.

Comment: @CraigEstey: cgroups are a completely different concept from pgroups/sessions – neither setpgrp nor setsid will have any effect on the process's cgroup membership. (Which is slightly deliberate, but mainly it's just that the two facilities have no relationship whatsoever.) Cgroup migration is done through /sys/fs/cgroup, and generally requires privileges; on systemd-based systems it's typically left to systemd rather than done manually. (Take a look at `systemd-cgls`.)

Comment: Side note: the point of the double `fork` is to relieve the original process from management responsibility for the grandchild.  The original process will not receive `SIGCHLD` when the grandchild terminates, and its `wait` / `waitpid` calls will not respond to the grandchild's events.  That's usually desirable in a situation like this.  The grandchild does not receive any particular benefit from that, however.  *Its* benefit comes from moving to a new session and / or process group, which it could do just as well as the immediate child.

Answer (score 1):

By a "linux service", you seem to mean a service managed via a SystemD service unit.  Not all Linux distros rely on systemd, and there can be other kinds of services even on a systemd-based system.

Among the relevant aspects of systemd-based services is that systemd uses Linux [*control groups*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html) (cgroups) to help manage them.  In particular, the recommended [kill modes](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.kill.html#) for systemd services (`control-group` and `mixed`) both are recommended exactly because they affect all processes in the service's cgroup.  I advise against trying to evade that: a service, whether systemd-managed or not, *should not* start processes that exit its sphere of control.

But **if you insist on having your service start processes that fully exit its control ("detach" from it)**, and if you want to start such processes by `fork()`ing them, then those processes that want to escape need to move themselves out of the service's cgroup.  The root of that cgroup hierarchy is `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd` on the systems with which I am familiar.  To escape the service's cgroup in this cgroup hierarchy, the process would write (a decimal representation of) either 0 or its pid to file `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/cgroup.procs`.  That should move it to the root cgroup of the hierarchy, out of systemd's control.

In that case, it would be wise to move the process to its own process group, too.  If the service is system-level then I would accomplish that by moving the process to a new session (`setsid()`), but if it is a user-level service then I would consider keeping it in the same session and changing just its process group (there's more than one way to do it, but I would choose `setpgid(0, 0)`).

Note that although you probably don't need to double fork (see [@Craig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78009556/2402272)) that might still be a good idea for the service's sake.  FWIW, double-`fork`ing is *always* for the original process's sake, not that of the grandchild.

Comment: The double `fork` was indeed not helping. Thanks for the explanation! I am not manipulating the cgroups manually for now but rely on `systemd-run` for the time being